# Analysis of Quality of Life Questionnaire

Tags: normal-distribution, survey, likert

I have conducted a questionnaire to assess patients' quality of life. There are 19 questions on a Likert type scale. There are 3 domains covered in the questionnaire (physical, social and psychological). I have responses for all questions plus a total score at the end.

The patients filled this in before and after treatment so I have 2 scores for each patient, plus a record of the difference.

I am now trying to statistically analyse this dataset. I understand that for testing reliability, I need to use Cronbach's alpha. However, beyond this I am unsure what further tests to do. I do not understand which test for normality and which test I can then use to assess whether there is a statistically significant difference between before and after.

I apologise for my lack of statistics knowledge

Comment: As you don't know a population standard deviation, a t test for a difference in mean scores seems appropriate.

Comment: I can get a standard deviation if necessary, however could I not check my 'before' and 'after' scores to assess for normal distribution and then test for significance on these based on the result? I am assuming my data is non-parametric

Comment: One of the requirements for the test I recommended is that the data follows a normal type distribution. If not, the assumption that the analysis follows a predictable pattern for probability is not valid. http://www.real-statistics.com/tests-normality-and-symmetry/

Comment: I see, so statistical significance from a t test would be sufficient? I was recommended a Wilcoxon signed rank test by someone else and figuring all this out is rather confusing! Would this data count as univariate or multivariate - I'm not sure how responses from a questionnaire are interpreted

Comment: The test I suggested was the most simple for a difference in total score. What other variables are you considering? Gender, age or are you wanting to analyze the data by domain?

Comment: I would like to look at the difference (for which you've suggested a t-test) and then if possible, the differences between the domains before and after and that's it. I am not in a position to compare anything like gender or age at this point

Comment: The Wilcoxon test is appropriate if the data is not normal. If you are wanting to analyze by domain you could run a t test on the data from each domain. A paired t test is better given the data is normal.

Comment: Would a t-test still apply for non-parametric data (I'm assuming mine is this)

Comment: Non-parametric just means that there is no assumption about the distribution. A test for the data being normal will determine which test to use of the 2 we've discussed.

Comment: I understand, and one final question (thank you for all your help) - does a questionnaire, and in this case my total scores, count as multivariate or univariate? I'm getting rather confused with the definitions

Comment: Are the scores a measure of the perceived improvement in quality of life without taking into account any other variables?

Comment: The final score is simply a sum of the 19 questions which as a perception of the patient on various aspects of their life e.g. anxiety, appearance. Apart from these questions, nothing else is considered e.g. gender, age etc

Comment: Anxiety, appearance etc are all variables in your data so this to me is multivariate.

Comment: Would this then not change any of the tests?

Comment: If you use a single t test, you cannot say that the result is a measure in the change of one of these variables. I guess it all depends on what you want to use the result for. If you want to know about one of the variables, you can run a t test on just the data in that category.

Comment: I see, so I could still do a t test on the difference but just state that I cannot say whether it's the independent variables? I'd essentially just be doing a univariate analysis? I essentially want to show a significant difference in total before and after scores

Comment: Yes that's correct. If the total score is your main interest, a paired t test is suitable and easy to run, and valid as long as your data is close to normal.